# jquery upgrade from 1.8.3 to 3.1.1 min js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

While upgrading from jQuery v1.8.3 to v3.1.1, the code is showing tooltips in incorrect places, like the end of the page. Also, draggable functions are not working.

Comment: What exactly are you asking about?

Comment: in jsp page the tooltips used are not appearing in proper place

Comment: @Dinesh share you jsp codes and elaborate your question

Comment: Hi @Aminul previously with 1.8.3 that page used to work correctly after upgrading it to 3.1.1 min js with 1.4.1 migrate file it is not working

Comment: Can you please add some error logs to your question, of what happens if you upgrade from 1.8.3 to  3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jQuery Migrate to pinpoint the deprecated/incorrect code in your jQuery functions. Call Migrate **after** your jQuery from this URL:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/3.0.0/jquery-migrate.min.js

Check your browser's console after adding the Migrate script and see what errors you have there. They should be pretty verbose and indicate the exact function and line number.

> This plugin can be used to warn about and/or restore APIs and
>   behaviors that have been deprecated and/or removed as of jQuery
>   version 3.0.

Reference: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>

Comment: used like above not able to load page properly

Comment: Check your browser's console and see what errors you have there.

Comment: Receiving errors like 1.Object doesn't support property or method 'live'undefinedundefined 2. Object doesn't support property or method 'apply'

Comment: Correct. `live()` is, indeed, undefined. You need to use `on()`. You will have to check the jQuery documentation on deprecated functions and what to replace them with.

Answer (score 0):

[migrate link](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate#note-to-upgrade-to-jquery-30-you-first-need-version-112x-or-22x-if-youre-using-an-older-version-first-upgrade-to-one-of-these-versions-using-jquery-migrate-1x-to-resolve-any-compatibility-issues-for-more-information-about-the-changes-made-in-jquery-30-see-the-upgrade-guide-and-blog-post) check this. if your current version of jquery is older than 2.2.x then use jQuery Migrate 1.x first to migrate to 1.9+ first